# fix sized div over flowing content issue

Tags: css

If I have fixed height for a content div, it's possible that the content will spill over the div. But the fixed height is to stop the footer from floating up into the middle of the page on pages with less content. In other words it's there so that the footer is in the same place on every page. How do I fix this?

Comment: your question is not really clear, do you want to stop the spillover of text or do you want to just keep the footer there?

Comment: showing some code would help me to answer more accurately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the min-height CSS property to define a minimum height for the content div, or position the footer absolutely with bottom: 0px

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need something like [New CSS Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There is a technique called **sticky footer**. It can help you with your problem:
http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/